# Getting like this connection string in the web.config file ReplacableToken_ when using web.config transform?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, web.config-transform

I have 2 different servers like development and production. So I have tried to the changed dynamically connection string and some key. 
I have like this 2 web.config file.

```
 1) Web.Develop.Config
 2) Web.Production.Config
```

Now On my web.config file, I have like this connection string and some keys.

```
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="localhost" />
 </connectionStrings>
 <add key="Email" value="abc@gmail.com" />
```

Now On my web.Develop.config file, like this set connection string and some keys.

```
  <add name="DefaultConnection"
    connectionString="develop"
    xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>

       <add key="Email" value="develop@gamil.com" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
```

Now On my web.Producation.config file, like this set connection string and some keys.

```
  <add name="DefaultConnection"
  connectionString="producation"
  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>

    <add key="Email" value="producation@gamil.com" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
```

So now I have Build and release with online **VSTS** and on a development server with my web.config file in Connection string is not changed. and like this show here below.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="$(ReplacableToken_develop- 
    Web.config Connection String_0)" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

But yes my Email is changed and I am getting a correct email address for a development server.

So anyone knows how can I fix this issue for dynamically changed connection string on the web.config file? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following

```
<add name="DefaultConnection"
connectionString="develop connection string"
xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Condition(@name='DefaultConnection')"/>
```